Academic Hosting for 10-Year South Atlantic Weather Dataset
I have compiled a 10-year South Atlantic weather dataset, totaling approximately 5 TB, and plan to write a dataset article based on it. I’m looking to host the dataset publicly either for free or at a reasonable cost. Can you recommend academic hosting platforms that accommodate large datasets and ensure easy access for researchers?

Probably the most widely known academic dataset host in the machine learning community is the UCI Machine Learning Repository. They should be able to host your dataset for free and it should receive high visibility. Here's the page with information on how to contribute: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/contribute/donation
